# Trying to read an online video using OpenCV in python, Not seeing the output but the code is not throwing any error

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-processing

Not sure what is the problem. Code is running fine and not showing any error. But Not seeing any output.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("https://youtu.be/_3elg-_1m_c")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If, I am using video saved in my laptop, I can see the output, but for online vidoes, I am not.

Comment: I guess you cannot do that since that is not the link to a youtube and not the 'video' you need to search for video url after you have loaded youtube on browser and try. You can first try to get any other online video working and then go ahead solving youtube. Try this link http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8?dummy=param.mjpg

Comment: As far as running the videos are concerned, I can very well do it if the video is saved in my laptop. However, The video URL i had taken from the youtube videos; I had righclicked the video and there you get the option of video URL; that's how I had done. Even the code is running fine. No error as such. But somehow not able to see the output.